Finding the index of a subrange containing a number, from a set of disjoint consecutive subranges
Given a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the range $T = [0..n)$ and the set of consecutive disjoint subranges $S = \{ \ [t_{i}..t_{i+1}) \ | \ 0 \le t_{i} \lt t_{i+1} \le n, \ i \ge 0 \ \}$ (i.e $\bigcup_{s \ \in \ S}s = T$) , $s \in S$ and $t \in s$, is there a way to map $t$ to the index of the subrange $s$?
e.g.
If
$n = 10$
$T = [0..10)$
$S = \{ \ [0..2), [2..5), [5..6), [6..9), [9..10) \ \} $
then
$map(0) = 0$
$map(3) = 1$
$map(8) = 3$
$map(10) = 4$
(0-based indices)
Or at least is there any relation that gives a chance at approximating the index (e.g. $map(t) \ge i$)?
I was trying to find such a relation by using the arithmetic average of the subrange sizes (i.e. $\frac{\sum_{s \ \in \ S}card(s)}{card(S)}$, or simply $\frac{n}{card(S)}$), but I could not get to a result.
P.S. I am sorry if the notations, terminology or the formatting are confusing. It is my first post on this site and my math is quite rusty. Any feedback is appreciated.

What exactly do you mean? Are you asking, given such a partition into disjoint ranges, if one can find for some $t\in[0,n)$ the index of the range it falls into? The easiest way to do this is to find the largest $t_i$ (from the list of left endpoints for a range) that satisfies $t_i\leq t$.

@AnCar That is exactly what I was trying to ask for. Indeed, the solution you provided is the easiest, and I already use this method by making use of a binary search. The problem is that I don't have all the disjoint ranges immediately available and the current method needs to load (as in, from a file) all ranges before applying the search, otherwise the search may fail if the range containing the desired value is not present. What I want to know is if there is any method to reduce the number of ranges that I have to load before applying the search.

Oh i see. I am not really a programmer. So not sure if my advice is too sensible. If you have  a method that inductively constructs the $t_i$, so a method that once you have $t_i$ returns $t_{i+1}$, you can call that in a while loop until you get that $t_i>t$.

If you don't have such a method and the $t_i$ could form an arbitrary increasing sequence, I don't think there is much you can do to optimize your runtime.
